# Group variables by values with % of each other

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I want to group rows of a df that have a certain column with values that are x% of each other.
For example in the df below a 10% difference in values would be grouped into 3 groups: (A, C,F), (B,D), (E).
So some kind of group by with a +/- 10% change in values.

```
tibble(Item = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), value = c(1.01,2.42,1.03,2.45, 3.1, 0.99))
```

Comment: What if 3 such values are 1, 1.09, 1.18 the percent being 10% only

Comment: In the case I am using this, such a condition is impossible so no need to worry about this.

Comment: Ok.  See the answer.  This will work in cases either (i) you wanna group them together or (ii) these kinda situation won't occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work. The "group" is then Item.

You can see there will be a number of edge cases because of the way you've specified it. You can drop the argument mult = "first" to parse them out.

```
dt <- data.table(tibble(Item = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), value = c(1.01,2.42,1.03,2.45, 3.1, 0.99)))
dt[, `:=`(lower_bound = value * .9,
          upper_bound = value * 1.1)]
dt[dt, on = .(value > lower_bound,
              value < upper_bound), mult = "first"][, .(i.Item), Item]

#    Item i.Item
# 1:    A      A
# 2:    A      C
# 3:    A      F
# 4:    B      B
# 5:    B      D
# 6:    E      E
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have clarified in your comments that sequential elements will not clash each other, you can do something like this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(value) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cumsum(lag(value, default = 0)*1.1 <= value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Item)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Item  value   grp
  <chr> <dbl> <int>
1 A      1.01     1
2 B      2.42     2
3 C      1.03     1
4 D      2.45     2
5 E      3.1      3
6 F      0.99     1
```

This will also produce expected results, if negative values may be there in `value`

```
df %>% arrange(value) %>% 
  group_by(grp = 1 + cumsum(lag(value, default = first(value))*1.1 <= value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  arrange(Item)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  Item  value   grp
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A      1.01     1
2 B      2.42     2
3 C      1.03     1
4 D      2.45     2
5 E      3.1      3
6 F      0.99     1
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick and dirty solution I would suggest:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(Item = c("A","B","C","D","E","F"), value = c(1.01,2.42,1.03,2.45, 3.1, 0.99))

df %>%
  mutate(group = ceiling((value/max(value))/0.1))
```

where you can vary the `0.1` divisor.